# Is there an R package to conduct a meta analysis using prevalence and variance?

Tags: meta-analysis

I am looking for an R package to conduct meta analysis for single proportions but where I can enter proportion and variance data rather than event + sample size (as I am trying to combine data from surveys that include survey weights and those that do not).

Metaprop (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/meta/versions/4.9-2/topics/metaprop) is exactly what I am trying to do BUT only accepts event + sample size so won't be helpful for my weighted data sets.